# Why cURL gives different output on server and localhost?

Tags: php, curl

The below code gives different output on localhost and server.
I tried changing useragents and browsers. Am I missing any header?

```
<?php

$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
$headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding   gzip,deflate';
$headers[] = 'Keep-Alive: 300';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7';
//$headers[] = 'Content-Length: 0';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'dbg_curl_data');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'dbg_curl_data');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en; rv:1.9.1.7) Gecko/20091221 Firefox/3.5.7');
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.facebook.com/login.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$html = curl_exec ($curl);
//curl_close ($curl);

echo '<fieldset><legend>request headers</legend>
<pre>', htmlspecialchars(curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT)), '</pre>
</fieldset>';

echo '<fieldset><legend>response</legend>
<pre>', htmlspecialchars(dbg_curl_data(null)), '</pre>
</fieldset>';

echo '<fieldset><legend>$html</legend>
<pre>', htmlspecialchars($html), '</pre>
</fieldset>';

function dbg_curl_data($curl, $data=null) {
 static $buffer = '';

 if ( is_null($curl) ) {
   $r = $buffer;
   $buffer = '';
   return $r;
 }
 else {
   $buffer .= $data;
   return strlen($data);
 }
}
?>
```

Output on Localhost : http://pastebin.com/UbpTVc4f

Output on Server : http://pastebin.com/NURDksJy

I want output as its on localhost.

Comment: You are doing post request without any post data?

Comment: nope I am not doing post request.

Comment: From the pages you have linked: `request headers POST /login.php HTTP/1.1`

Comment: thats because curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); was there. If I make it comment then it still yields different output.

Comment: So now you are sending `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8` with GET request.

Comment: I made that piece of code a comment. Still it doesn't help.

Comment: I'm running it now and it works. There's likely some other code not in your post that ruins it. Server returns me on your core `HTTP/1.1 302 Found`.

Comment: but $html variable has different values on server and localhost. upload it somewhere and browse it.

Comment: The page you requesting does not give "200 OK" response. It gives "302 Found" and redirects to 'https' version. This means your localhost request is actually quite fishy. See the CURLOPT_EFFECTIVE_URL of the page it actually grabs

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start with something simple before you complicate your request as much as it is now and is hard to debug. For example, this code (run it in a separate file):

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en; rv:1.9.1.7) Gecko/20091221 Firefox/3.5.7');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.facebook.com/login.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$html = curl_exec ($curl);
print_r($html);
```

Should give you `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` in return.